# SQL Server : get unique ID from one table, another table, or both

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, TA and CMI, that contain a `person_ID`. The `ID` may exist in TA, it may exist in CMI, or it may exist in both. I want a distinct list of ALL `person_ID`'s regardless whether they are in TA, CMI, or both tables.

I also want to be able to select them where their question_ID's are the same.  However, the question_id's have different column names: TA.question and CMI.sco = question_id.

EDIT:

So, if I also wanted to do the select on question as I stated earlier AND a join to the person table, it would look something like:

```
select ta.person_id, person_key
from ta 
left join person on person.person_id = ta.person_id
where question=7033
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select cmi.person_id, person_key
from cmi 
left join person on person.person_id = cmi.person_id
where sco=7033
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `union`:

```
select person_id
from ta
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select person_id
from cmi;
```

You can use this as a CTE or subquery in a query.